# I want to mimic different browser location

Tags: proxy, vpn

I am connected to my office VPN and while being connected I wnat to spoof different location.
Like I am sitting in UK but i want my browser location to be india.

How can I do this?
Is there any free extension available to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use extensions such as Change Geolocation (Location Guard), Manual geolocation, and many other Location spoofers. OR:

Press `Ctrl+Shift+I`. Now click on the vertical ellipsis (⠇) in window that appears. Now select `More tools` then click on `Sensors` Now, at the bottom you will see a box showing `No override` by default. Click on that dropdown menu and choose the location listed or click and other to choose your own.
[image]
[image]

If you chose `Other`, then enter the coordinates manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a gps-sdr-sim on GitHub and a HackRF SDR to generate fake GPS signals.